# Get reference to image map area elements with JavaScript in IE8+

Tags: javascript, html, imagemap, area

I'm trying to get references with JavaScript to area elements in an image map, but in IE8+ it's not working.

My HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="image.png" usemap="#hotspots">
    <map name="#hotspots">
        <area id="seg-1" href="" shape="poly" coords="167,286,113,379,320,379,266,286,167,286"/>
        <area... />
        <area... />
        <area... />
        ...
    </map>
</div>
```

My JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("seg-1");
```

I assign a traditional event handler like this:

```
document.getElementById("seg-1").onmouseup = function() {alert("onmouseup called");};
```

This works in:

- Safari 6 (OS X)
- Chrome 26 (OS X)
- Firefox 21 (OS X)
- Chrome 27 (XP)
- Chrome 27 (W7)
- Chrome (W8).

But not in:

- IE8 (XP)
- IE9 (W7)
- IE10 (W8)
- Firefox 17 (XP)
- Firefox 21 (W7)
- Firefox 21 (W8).

When I run:

```
console.log(document.getElementById("seg-1"));
```

I get the element for the above browsers that work, but I get the URL of the page in the above browsers that don't work.

Any ideas how I can make this work?

PS: here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Stimpski/Y5jeJ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite of a nasty looking `console.log()`, `document.getElementById("seg-1")` refers to the HTML element, it's just `area`'s `toString()` method showing an url.

The reason why this is not working for some browsers is the name of the `map`. You should not use `#` in the `name` attribute of the `map`. `#` is needed only in `usemap` attribute of the `img`.